# iOS: send customized uint8 array

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to make an app that communicate iPhone with another hardware using dock to RS232 wire (I bought from RedPark). I'm also using the library provided by redpark. I made a simple code at beginning, it worked fine. 
    UInt8 infoCmd[5] = {0x3E,0x3E,0x05,0x80,0xff};
    [rscMgr write:infoCmd Length:5];
Then I want to add more command to it, so I create a method that returns different combinations of command I need.

```
- (UInt8 *)requestCommand:(int)commandName{
    UInt8 * command;
    if (commandName == DATADUMP) {
        command=[Communication buildDataDump];
    }
    if (commandName == GETSERIALINFO) {
        command=[Communication buildGetSerailInfo];   
    }
    return command;
}
+ (UInt8 *)buildGetSerailInfo{
    UInt8 *command = malloc(sizeof(UInt8)*5);
    command[0]=SYN;
    command[1]=SYN;
    command[2]=ENQ;
    command[3]=GETSERIALINFO;
    //command[4] = {SYN, SYN, ENQ, GETSERIALINFO};
    return command;    
}
```

The thing is, some of my commands includes data that can be 200 bytes long. How can I create an UInt8 array that is easier for me to add bytes?
I'm new to programming, please explain to me in detail. Thank you a lot in advance.

Comment: How can you be new to programming when you are working with UInt8s and 'C' functions in objective-c?

Comment: Not to mention sending and receiveing out a serial port, and malloc, etc...?

Comment: //please explain to me in detail// If you can't even understand the code you're putting out now, how can you expect us to give you a detailed answer about it?

Comment: To max_: I've learned a little bit coding in school years ago, but have never worked on it after the basic c class. To trumpetlicks: I worked on labview for a while of serial port. And have been working on this projects for two months now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you will just send data, row byte over the wire. I do something similar in one project (not wire, but RS232 commands over TCP/IP), and it becomes quite simple, if you use an NSMutableData instance.

A snippet from my code:

```
static u_int8_t codeTable[] =   { 0x1b, 0x74, 0x10 };
static u_int8_t charSet[]   =   { 0x1b, 0x52, 0x10 };
static u_int8_t formatOff[] =   { 0x1b, 0x21, 0x00 };
static u_int8_t reverseOn[] =   { 0x1d, 0x42, 0x01 };
static u_int8_t reverseOff[]=   { 0x1d, 0x42, 0x00 };
static u_int8_t paperCut[]  =   { 0x1d, 0x56, 0x0 };  


NSMutableData *mdata = [NSMutableData dataWithBytes:&formatOff length:sizeof(formatOff)];
[mdata appendBytes:&formatOff length:sizeof(formatOff)];
[mdata appendBytes:&reverseOff length:sizeof(reverseOff)];    
[mdata appendData: [NSData dataWithBytes: &codeTable length:sizeof(codeTable)]];
[mdata appendData: [NSData dataWithBytes: &charSet length:sizeof(charSet)]];
```

As you see, I am just appending the data byte by byte.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was asking.

Comment: I have another question. I create a NSMutableData and try to send data using [rscMgr write:data Length:5]. Error:It gave me an error and a warning: Implicit conversion of an Objective-C pointer to 'UInt8 *' (aka 'unsigned char *') is disallowed with ARC               Warning: Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSMutableData *__strong' to parameter of type 'UInt8 *' (aka 'unsigned char *')                    Do you have any suggestions on have solve this?

Comment: please try `[rscMgr write:&data Length:5]`

Comment: I bought the RedPark hardware, and they provided a library to help develop. RscMgr is a NSObject they provide too contains the communication agreement (Baud rate, parity...). - (int) write:(UInt8 *)data Length:(UInt32)length;   I change (UInt8 *)data into (NSMutableData *)data, the warning and error are gone. Let me try if it works. :)

Comment: Hi, just to update. I tested the code. I wanted to send a command {0x7A, 0x7A, 0x05, 0x8B}, but it sent {18 C8 79 3F 02 18 C8 79 3F 02}.I was thinking maybe NSMutableData will encode it before sending out? So I searched online and found this code works for me:    Byte * byteData = (Byte *)malloc(length); memcpy (byteData,[mutableData bytes], length);